# How can I span my RDP session to two screens without having it full screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I am able to get my RDP sessions to span multiple monitors without issue but only in full screen mode. From there I can take it out of full screen and resize the session keeping my two screens. I can resize it across my two desktops with some playing around but it's a pain.

Is there any way to change the RDP file's settings to enable two virtual screens across my two physical screens without first going into full screen in multimonitor mode?

Not sure how to better describe, but basically looking to keep my physical machine's taskbar visible while using RDP and still having access to dual screens.

I live in nested remote sessions and am constantly toggling between them, opening and closing to dozen machines. Having to resize each manually after being in full screen is driving me mad.

Comment: you will probably need an alternative RDP client. there are a few out there.

Comment: I normally solve this by editing the RDP file with a textfile and put a custom resolution in there. That does mean you have one window that spans both screens, and as such the taskbar on the remote will span both screens and can make an app have part of it on one screen and part of it on the other. Not ideal

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you, that’s what I thought. Tried Microsoft Store remote app but that doesn’t seem to support multiple remote monitors. Do you have any app suggestions?

Comment: @LPChip ya that was another alternative I was playing with. Unfortunately it doesn’t work for me because I have nested remote sessions so I hop to a remote network using a hop machine and then remote into multiple servers. It’s switching between those remote servers that is challenging and I often put one nested rdp on each screen.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can edit the RDP and force a resolution inside. It will then always create a window of that size. Alternatively, you can enable smart sizing so that you can resize the window to a smaller size while having a larger desktop. Text will be harder to read though.

Comment: @LPChip for now I've set `smart sizing:i:1` and `allow font smoothing:i:1` (otherwise font is mostly illegible). That seems to at least make it a bit easier to use, but still have to do a weird workaround of making it fullscreen initially, then taking it out of fullscreen and manually spanning it. Thank you for at least saving me some sanity.

Comment: You can specify the dimensions too the same way you did smart sizing, and that should do it directly from the start. RDP can be entirely configured to start the way you want if you manage to get the right settings in place.